# saving content of terminal in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, scrolling

We can scroll up/down using shift+up/down to see the content of terminal. but is there any way by which we can save the whole content in file. Since we can see the content, so I think there must  be a buffer or file which is managed by the operating system. I need this to search through the content using grep ( manually going up/down and looking for desired text is cumbersome.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using gnome-terminal, you can use "script" to log everything in a terminal as mentioned [here](http://denraf.be/category/tagcloud/terminal-logging).
If you're using konsole, I think you can you can hit (don't have a system handy to double check)

```
Edit->Save History As
```

There was supposed to be a patch to gnome-terminal to allow the same, but I don't know if it was ever implemented.
Otherwise you can simply highlight what you want and save it to buffer then open your favorite editor.

Comment: seems script need to be done manually each time. I was wondering there must be some buffer where terminal's output is saved.

Comment: Though i found these steps useful, # Use <shift>Home to seek to the top of the buffer.
# Use mouse button 1 to drag across the top line, (or triple-click to do it).
# Use <shift>End to seek to the bottom of the buffer.
# Use <shift> and mouse button 1 to extend the selection to the bottom line. then copy and paste anywhere you want.